How to find the minimum distance between two matrices in python? (special definitions)
I have 4 permutation matrices A, B, C, D.
we define the distance d(C, D)  to be the minimal number of matrix multiplications needed to satisfy the equation D = X.C.Y where the dot is matrix multiplication and X and Y are some sort of product of A, B, A^-1, B^-1 (for example X = A.A.B^-1, Y = B.B^-1.A^-1).
We were given a hint to use BFS and the following examples which result in d(C1, D1) = 3 and d(C2, D2) = 8.

# for these the distance d(C1, D1) is 3
A1 = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
B1 = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
C1 = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
D1 = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])


#for these the distance d(C2, D2) is 8
A2 = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
      [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])

B2 = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

C2 = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])

D2 = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])

and I'm tasked with finding the distance to the following matrices:

A = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]

B = [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]

C = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

D = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]


I've tried to do it with a double-sided queue and it seemed like it worked but when I submitted my answer it was wrong, the prof isn't responding to emails, and also when he answers you end up more confused than you began with.
so I'm looking for suggestions to solve this problem, we're not limited to any package/library
btw this is what I did at first:

import numpy as np
from collections import deque


def bfs_min_multiplications(A, A_inv, B, B_inv, C, D):
    # Convert matrices to numpy arrays for easier manipulation
    A = np.array(A)
    A_inv = np.array(A_inv)
    B = np.array(B)
    B_inv = np.array(B_inv)
    C = np.array(C)
    D = np.array(D)

    # Initialize the queue with the initial state (C) and 0 multiplications
    queue = deque([(C, 0, [])])
    visited = set()
    visited.add(tuple(C.flatten()))

    while queue:
        current_matrix, steps, path = queue.popleft()

        # Check if we have reached the goal state
        if np.array_equal(current_matrix, D):
            return steps, path

        # Generate all possible next states
        for matrix, name in [(A, 'A'), (A_inv, 'A^-1'), (B, 'B'), (B_inv, 'B^-1')]:
            for operation, op_name in [(np.dot(matrix, current_matrix), f"{name}.C"),
                                       (np.dot(current_matrix, matrix), f"C.{name}")]:
                operation_tuple = tuple(operation.flatten())
                if operation_tuple not in visited:
                    visited.add(operation_tuple)
                    queue.append((operation, steps + 1, path + [op_name]))

    return -1, []  # If no solution is found


I can assume that the problem is that you don't check AA-1 and BB-1 pairs - the correct solution cannot have them (such pairs reduce to an identical matrix) that's why you shouldn't append A to the queue, which ends with A-1 and vice versa

Also, can you specify "answer was wrong" means there was some numeric check and it means your function gives wrong answer, or it means that prof just don't like something

Note that since you use permutation matrices, the inverse (A^-1) must be equal to the transpose (A^T, or A.T). Actually, the problem D = XCY should have two obvious solutions: D = D.C.C^-1 or D = C^-1.C.D, since C.C^-1 = C^-1.C = I. You may be able to reduce the problem to a simpler version of finding X = D and Y = C^-1 = C^T
